# Knights tour on a 4 x m board

Tags: graph-theory, knight-tours

Prove that on a chessboard that has dimension $4 \times m$ there doesn't exist a knights tour in which we return to square we started at.

I know that we need to turn each square into a vertice and then add edges between vertices where a valid move exists.  Now we must show that this graph is not Hamiltonian, which I am unsure how to do.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Show that since you can't move between rows 1 and 4, in a (supposed!) Tour you can't move between rows 2 and 3 either.

So, what are all the colors of the squares visited in rows 2 and 3 like in such a Tour?

Comment: The only thing I am seeing is that they all have degree 3, other than that I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Ah, right, I was confused with an Eulerian cycle :(

Comment: @JustinStevenson Ok, new HINT!

Comment: Why can't you move between row 2 and 3?

Comment: Not if you want a Hamiltonian tour ... how many squares are there in rows 1 and 4?  How many are there in rows 2 and 3?

Comment: There would be m squares in each row correct?

Comment: Right. So a tour would have to visit just as many squares in rows 1 and 4 (2m) as there are squares in rows 2 and 3 (also 2m). Since you can;t move between rows 1 and 4, do you now see why in such a tour I couldn't move between rows 2 and 3 either?

Comment: Ahh yes I see that now.   how do I conclude its non Hamiltonian from that.

Comment: @JustinStevenson OK, suppose I start my tour in row 1 on a black square. We just showed that two jumps later I have to be in row 1 or 4... what is the color of that square?

Comment: It would have to be a black square.

Comment: @JustinStevenson So now you see why the tour is impossible, right?

Comment: Yes, because we cannot hit any white square in row's 1 and 4.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JustinStevenson You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this through colouring the squares like so

```
1 B 1 B 1 B 1 B ...
2 A 2 A 2 A 2 A ...
A 2 A 2 A 2 A 2 ...
B 1 B 1 B 1 B 1 ...
```

You start from the top left corner with colour $1$. Every field $1$ is preceeded and followed by a $2$. Because every field has to be in the tour, all $1$'s and $2$'s are in the sequence of moves, whereby the number of $1$'s and $2$'s are the same.

But the $A$'s must also lie in the sequence. In order to do that, there are only these two cases:

- *Case 1*: To get to an $A$, you are coming from a $2$. In this case, to get to a $1$, you have to go to a $2$ first in oder to do that, i.e. you have more $2$'s then $1$'s. Contradiction. An example would be like
  $$\ldots \rightarrow \underline{1 \rightarrow 2} \rightarrow A \rightarrow \boxed2 \rightarrow \underline{1 \rightarrow 2} \rightarrow \ldots$$
  or like
  $$\ldots \rightarrow \underline{1 \rightarrow 2} \rightarrow \underline{A \rightarrow B} \rightarrow A \rightarrow \boxed2 \rightarrow \underline{1 \rightarrow 2} \rightarrow \ldots$$
  Note that the boxed $2$ isn't in a pair with a $1$.
- *Case 2*: To get to an $A$, you are coming from a $B$. Like the $1$'s, every $B$ is preceeded and followed by an $A$. Therefore, to get to this $B$, you have to come from an $A$, so there is no first $A$ you moved to. Contradiction.

Therefore there is no colosed tour on the board.

**Additional note:** This solution is from the excellent and highly recommended book *Problem-Solving Strategies* by *Arthur Engel*. Some olympiad problems you will face come from this book. There's also a lot of must-no-theory in there. Give it a try: [PDF link](http://www.albertstam.com/Problem-solving_strategies_for_math_olympiads__1998_by_Arthur_Engel.pdf).